# Is Service accounts possible in Facebook for Developers?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

**Does Facebook allow to create anything like a [Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) in Google Cloud Platform?**

I need automated access to our FB Page via API, currently i can create [User Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens), but it is directly connected with my Personal account. I know, I can [generate Page Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#page-access-tokens), but it still covered by my User Access Token – then I revoke it, the Page Access Token is revoked too ([live example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/?access_token=EAAJUcrS1s1EBAInk1RqtfqLYJcEj8MQGcZCLFf0dZAgLbEXPoTWJ9FnEEJzW1ZAalrsBGIMAi9aZB2p7qwESzxK2EcqMqwHnTUXDOPBBsxWiKveDxPBFQJr76xnsQFwkZCwbibgZBHEOKGE6l6InZCj0xYZCiwh3mCGygHAfcdqvOZC7QVlB4XcZBnRXAZC5eStFZBHB4hAaHYeabZAD0OCt0ZBFmg&version=v4.0)).

Is here way to create something like Service account which was not been directly connected to any User's profile?

My reason is: I want to create app to my employer which is connect to Page in non-user context (it's reading Page's events), that must still live when I leave the company 
 (and revoke my personal User Access Token) or when my Personal Account was disabled (for any reason).

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/systemuser

Comment: _“(it's reading Page's events)”_ - you know that is currently only available to white-listed partners, right? And not available for normal 3rd-party apps?